# php: UPDATE SET function not updating table

Tags: php

I have a function to update a table but it does not work. My php error log does not report anything being wrong either so I am a bit stuck.

Here is the code:

```
    if (count($errors) == 0) {
    $query = "UPDATE wotd SET spanish='$spanish', english='$english', sex='$sex', example_es='$example_es', example_en='$example_en', description='$description' WHERE id=$wotd_id";
    $_SESSION['message'] = "WORD updated successfully";
    header('location: words.php');
    exit(0);
```

Comment: what does $query do at all? All I see is a string, are you executing that command anywhere?

Comment: I have just figured it out now. I am missing a line underneath the $query. mysqli_query($conn, $query);

Comment: You should use prepared statements and parameterize query.

Answer (score 0):

My code was incomplete and therefore not posting the data to the database.
I needed to add another line below $query = "INSERT..."

This is my updated code:

```
    if (count($errors) == 0) {
    $query = "UPDATE wotd SET spanish='$spanish', english='$english', sex='$sex', example_es='$example_es', example_en='$example_en', description='$description' WHERE id=$wotd_id";
    mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    $_SESSION['message'] = "WORD updated successfully";
    header('location: words.php');
    exit(0);
}
```